# javascript to python dictionary help needed

Tags: javascript, python

I need some help extracting javascript data to my python programme.

```
    soup = BeautifulSoup(wm, "html.parser")
    scripts = soup.findAll('script')
    s = scripts[:50]
    print(s)
```

Using the above i am getting the below output - again within a javascript

I am looking to extract the data below from this - any help would be much appreciated!

In essence i am looking to get the items.push> saved as a python dictionary.

```
        var items = [];

    


        items.push({

            'item_id': '196388',

            'item_name': 'Rolex Submariner 116610 LN',

            'item_brand': 'Rolex',

            'item_collection': 'Submariner',

            'item_variant': '116610 LN',

            'item_category': 'watch',

            'price': '12500',

            'currency': 'GBP',

            'quantity': '1',

            'item_material_case': 'Steel',

            'item_material_strap': 'Steel (Oyster)',

            'item_dial': 'Black',

            'item_size': '40',

            'item_box': 'True',

            'item_papers': 'True',

            'item_special_edition': 'False',

            'item_available': 'instock',

            'item_sellable': 'sellable',

            'item_year': '2013'



            });

        


        items.push({

            'item_id': '211954',

            'item_name': 'Rolex Submariner 116610 LN',

            'item_brand': 'Rolex',

            'item_collection': 'Submariner',

            'item_variant': '116610 LN',

            'item_category': 'watch',

            'price': '12400',

            'currency': 'GBP',

            'quantity': '1',

            'item_material_case': 'Steel',

            'item_material_strap': 'Steel (Oyster)',

            'item_dial': 'Black',

            'item_size': '40',

            'item_box': 'True',

            'item_papers': 'True',

            'item_special_edition': 'False',

            'item_available': 'preorder',

            'item_sellable': 'sellable',

            'item_year': '2012'



            });
```

Comment: Copy paste? lol

Comment: with open("file_name.html", "r") as wm: soup = BeautifulSoup(wm, "html.parser") scripts = soup.findAll('script') s = scripts[:50] print(s) Is the code that i am running, im not sure if i am over complicating it or if in-fact it is worth using BeautifulSoup

Comment: I have also tried:

rows  = contentTable.findAll('a', title = re.compile('^items.push .*'))
print(rows)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your data I think you fetch them from an API, so given the endpoint you can get the dict using this:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(endpoint)
json = response.json() // your dict
```

Comment: with open("file_name.html", "r") as wm:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(wm, "html.parser")
    scripts = soup.findAll('script')
    s = scripts[:50]
    print(s)

Is the code that i am running, im not sure if i am over complicating it or if in-fact it is worth using BeautifulSoup.